# php - set photo to image by path

Tags: php, html

Well, my page contains an `img` like this:

`<img id=".."class=".." src="setPhoto/second_photo.php">`

Now, as you can see in src I have put a .php file:

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    mysql_close($link);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $row['profile_front_photo'];
} else {
    // no result from database
    mysql_close($link);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo '../../../_images/default.jpg'; //Here is the promblem
}

?>
```

This code with the path, is not working. I want to set a photo to `img` by using a path.

Is it possible?

Comment: first you have to retrieve photo from db & then set to src... In code you are going with opposite direction... do not add .php file in src

Comment: can you paste your output

Comment: You dont know  what is path of default.jpg. First check what is the absolute or relative path of default.jpg according to your folder structure, then just form that path into a variable and pass it to the echo statement or image SRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser asked for an image. Instead of getting an image back, it got back a string "../../../_images/default.jpg".

Instead, you want to open that file and pass its contents through. You also need to set the correct MIME type in the response.

You should be able to find simple tutorials for this online, or take a look at e.g. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Comment: My image is keep showing nothing. Why?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

it will get the root folder your project and then you specified your path like this

```
dirname(__FILE__). '/imagefoldername/_images/default.jpg';
```

Comment: that won't help at all. see my answer

Answer (score -1):

Make it

```
$path='../../../_images/default.jpg';
echo "<img src='.$path.'>";
```